# How do you make unsalted olives?

Tags: oil, salt, fermentation, curing, olive

How do I cure olives without using salt? Is oil the only option? Or salt free fermentation of some sort?

I found [this one](https://oliveology.co.uk/product/unsalted-olives/) claiming to be unsalted but couldn't find any recipe/resource describing the process?

Comment: Curing and fermentation are different processing method on food. What purpose do you want for olives? Extend the preserving time or transforming the flavor on olives?

Comment: Just making them edible as I read you can't eat olives raw (without curing/preparing) I will be storing them in the freezer so preservation is less of a concern

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Oven-dried olives are your only non-salted option.

Long answer:

Almost all olive cures involve some quantity of salt. Some olives are just brined; [olives cured with lye](https://www.thespruceeats.com/lye-cured-green-olives-recipe-1807881) are also brined; so-called "[oil-cured olives](https://honest-food.net/how-to-make-oil-cured-olives/)" are actually heavily salted.

Your only non-salted option are "[oven-dried olives](https://notesfromatuscanolivegrove.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/curing-olives-1-drying-the-lazy-way/)", a Tuscan specialty ... but they won't taste like the olives you're used to.  You might try them anyway.  I'll warn you though -- they're better if you add a little salt.

Comment: I just read [here](https://oliveology.co.uk/glossary/fresh-water-curing/) they use "fresh water curing" where they naturally ferment the olives completely salt free over 6-9 months- is this done by simply changing the water every single day?

Comment: Beats me, I've never heard of that method before and I'm frankly a little dubious.

Comment: It says on their [page](https://oliveology.co.uk/product/unsalted-olives/) they took 4 years to develop that "close guarded" method, I can well imagine how dubious that sounds